# How do I resize a field manually in tableau without others resizing automatically?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to resize a field manually without the others being affected. How can this be done?

Pict 1 is how it is currently displayed
Pict 2 is when I try to resize MIN(0). The others also resizes as a result. How to avoid that?

Thank you

**Pict 1 and Pict 2**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Their is only one image attached

Comment: Sorry. The image is 1 below the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as of 2019.2.